# How do I figure out which module defines an exception during an interactive session

Tags: python, exception, read-eval-print-loop

Within an interactive Python session, how can I determine which in which module a given exception is defined?

I am looking for a solution that can be executed using only the python shell in order to avoid the context switching between my development environment and the browser and to have a solution that works well for poorly documented packages.

My specific case:  I'm working on a Django application.  The Django framework ORM raises a `DoesNotExist` error when you try to get an object from the DB that does not exist.  In order to catch that exception, I need to determine where it is defined so that I can import that module.

```
# make a new UUID just to ensure that the exception is raised
In [4]: models.Selection.objects.get(pk=uuid.uuid4())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DoesNotExist                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-aeb92642cdc2> in <module>
----> 1 models.Selection.objects.get(pk=uuid.uuid4())

~/app-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     83         def create_method(name, method):
     84             def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 85                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
     86             manager_method.__name__ = method.__name__
     87             manager_method.__doc__ = method.__doc__

~/app-dev/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    433             return clone._result_cache[0]
    434         if not num:
--> 435             raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
    436                 "%s matching query does not exist." %
    437                 self.model._meta.object_name

DoesNotExist: Selection matching query does not exist.

# in the shell, how do I figure out what module defines the DoesNotExist exception?
```

I am aware that in this specific case I can search the Django documentation, but again want a general, non-browser based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just catch any exception, then print out the type of the exception:

```
In [7]: try:
   ...:     models.Selection.objects.get(pk=uuid.uuid4())
   ...: except Exception as e:
   ...:     print(type(e))
 <class 'channels.models.Selection.DoesNotExist'>
```